# How to make a new version of an npm module

Tags: node.js, npm

I have created a npm module and published it via `npm publish`.
The question is how to make a new version for the same module and publish it?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages#updating-the-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the "version" in your `package.json` and `npm publish` again .

**Edit after comments :**

Or run `npm version patch|major|minor` as mentioned in the docs and it will update the `package.json` for you as well as make a tag in git

Comment: Or run `npm version patch|major|minor` as mentioned in the docs and it will update the `package.json` for you as well as make a tag in git

Comment: How simple was to do it. Thank you.